# Conditional Postback though ICallbackEventHandler implemented

Tags: c#, .net, icallbackeventhandler

I am new to .net programming. I have a custom control which implements ICallbackEventHandler. This control has dropdowns.  On one of these dropdowns I need a postback, since the entire page needs to be reloaded as per the value selected. I know ICallbackEventHandler is used to avoid postbacks. But is this conditional postback achievable? I dont want to make changes to the control since it is an old code and used at many places. Hence I do not want to redesign the existing control and get rid of ICallbackEventHandler. Please suggest alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try catching the dropdown indexChanged event and fire a custom even handler which will do a postback.